# Can't load generated public key from NodeJS into Windows via CNG APIs

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, windows, cryptography

I generate RSA public/private key pairs in NodeJS using `crypto` library:

```
crypto.generateKeyPair(
    "rsa",
    {
        modulusLength: 1024,
        publicKeyEncoding: {
            type: "pkcs1",
            format: "pem",
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
            type: "pkcs1",
            format: "pem",
        },
    },
    (err, publicKey, privateKey) => {
        fs.writeFileSync("/home/dev/priv.pem", privateKey);
        fs.writeFileSync("/home/dev/pub.pem", publicKey);
    } );
```

Now when I want to load the public key using Windows Cryptographic CNG APIs, it fails. `CryptDecodeObjectEx` returns 0x8009310b (ASN1 bad tag value error). I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68376081/3144560) link to load public key. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Should I generate the keys in a specific way?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Wow it actually worked! Thank you very much. Why it should be spki? Isn't it standard pkcs RSA key?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sorry one more question: When I fill my buffer, BCryptEncrypt only works with BCRYPT_PAD_NONE. But when data is less than keySize, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1 works. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you very much. You can write your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the "pkcs1" string with "spki". That code doesn't expect an RSA key, it expects a SubjectPublicKeyInfo encoded key.

SPKI is defined in the X.509 standard, it allows the ASN.1 encoding to indicate any kind of key. It could also incorporate an Elliptic Curve based key of various types, for instance. Internally it contains the PKCS#1 encoded key, but in this case the indicator for the type of key - in this case an RSA key - is in the binary encoding instead of the text encoding.

Notes:

- You should not use "textbook RSA", and always use some kind of secure padding such as PKCS#1 padding or OAEP padding. `BCRYPT_PAD_NONE` is only useful if you define your own scheme or implement another existing scheme, which is probably best avoided. Look at hybrid cryptography (encrypting an AES key, for instance) if you want to encrypt larger message.
- A 1024 bit key is considered too small nowadays; please use a key of at least 2048 bits.
- You might want to look at container formats such as CMS or even PGP instead of performing the RSA encryption directly.

Answer (score 1):

different blocks of PEM (between `-----BEGIN X-----` ... `-----END X-----`), have different format. so need use different constants in call to `CryptDecodeObjectEx` in place *lpszStructType*. common - that first we need convert base64 to binary (use `CryptStringToBinaryA` ). than use call to `CryptDecodeObjectEx` with *lpszStructType* base on `X`.

```
template <typename T> 
T HR(HRESULT& hr, T t)
{
    hr = t ? S_OK : GetLastError();
    return t;
}

NTSTATUS ImportRsaKey(_Out_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKey, _In_ PCWSTR pszBlobType, _In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb)
{
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm;
    NTSTATUS status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlgorithm, BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM, 0, 0);
    if (0 <= status)
    {
        status = BCryptImportKeyPair(hAlgorithm, 0, pszBlobType, phKey, pb, cb, 0);
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0);
    }

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS ImportEccKey(_Out_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKey, _In_ PCRYPT_ECC_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO p, _In_ UCHAR IsEncrypt)
{
    PCCRYPT_OID_INFO pOidInfo = CryptFindOIDInfo(IsEncrypt 
        ? CRYPT_OID_INFO_OID_KEY|CRYPT_OID_INFO_PUBKEY_ENCRYPT_KEY_FLAG 
        : CRYPT_OID_INFO_OID_KEY|CRYPT_OID_INFO_PUBKEY_SIGN_KEY_FLAG, 
        p->szCurveOid, 
        CRYPT_PUBKEY_ALG_OID_GROUP_ID | CRYPT_OID_PREFER_CNG_ALGID_FLAG);

    if (!pOidInfo)
    {
        return STATUS_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    if (pOidInfo->cbSize < sizeof(CRYPT_OID_INFO) ||
        !pOidInfo->pwszCNGAlgid ||
        !pOidInfo->ExtraInfo.pbData ||
        pOidInfo->ExtraInfo.cbData < 3 * sizeof(ULONG))
    {
        return STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR;
    }

    ULONG cbKey = p->PrivateKey.cbData;

    if (1 + (cbKey << 1) != p->PublicKey.cbData)
    {
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    ULONG cb = sizeof(BCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB) + cbKey * 3;
    PBCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB pecc = (PBCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB)alloca(cb);
    pecc->cbKey = cbKey;
    pecc->dwMagic = ((ULONG*)pOidInfo->ExtraInfo.pbData)[1] + 0x01000000;
    PBYTE pb = (PBYTE)(pecc+1);

    memcpy(pb, p->PublicKey.pbData + 1, cbKey << 1);
    memcpy(pb + (cbKey << 1), p->PrivateKey.pbData, cbKey);

    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm;
    NTSTATUS status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlgorithm, pOidInfo->pwszCNGAlgid, 0, 0);
    if (0 <= status)
    {
        status = BCryptImportKeyPair(hAlgorithm, 0, BCRYPT_ECCPRIVATE_BLOB, phKey, (PUCHAR)pecc, cb, 0);
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0);
    }

    return status;
}

UCHAR IsEncryptKey(PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTES pAttributes)
{
    if (pAttributes)
    {
        if (DWORD cAttr = pAttributes->cAttr)
        {
            UCHAR Usage = 0;

            PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTE rgAttr = pAttributes->rgAttr;

            do 
            {
                if (!strcmp(szOID_KEY_USAGE, rgAttr->pszObjId))
                {
                    if (DWORD cValue = rgAttr->cValue)
                    {
                        PCRYPT_ATTR_BLOB rgValue = rgAttr->rgValue;
                        do 
                        {
                            ULONG cb;
                            PCRYPT_BIT_BLOB KeyUsage;

                            if (CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, X509_KEY_USAGE, 
                                rgValue->pbData, rgValue->cbData, 
                                CRYPT_DECODE_NOCOPY_FLAG|CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG, 0, &KeyUsage, &cb))
                            {
                                Usage |= (*KeyUsage->pbData & 
                                    (CERT_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE|CERT_DATA_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE|CERT_ENCIPHER_ONLY_KEY_USAGE));

                                if (KeyUsage->cbData > 1)
                                {
                                    Usage |= (KeyUsage->pbData[1] & CERT_DECIPHER_ONLY_KEY_USAGE);
                                }
                                LocalFree(KeyUsage);
                            }

                        } while (rgValue++, --cValue);
                    }
                }
            } while (rgAttr++, --cAttr);

            return Usage;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

HRESULT PkcsImportPlainTextKey(_Out_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKey, _In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb)
{
    PCRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO PrivateKeyInfo;

    HRESULT hr;

    if (HR(hr, CryptDecodeObjectEx(
        X509_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO, pb, cb, 
        CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG|CRYPT_DECODE_NOCOPY_FLAG|CRYPT_DECODE_SHARE_OID_STRING_FLAG, 
        0, &PrivateKeyInfo, &cb)))
    {
        PSTR pszObjId = PrivateKeyInfo->Algorithm.pszObjId;

        PCSTR lpszStructType = 0;

        if (!strcmp(pszObjId, szOID_RSA_RSA))
        {
            lpszStructType = CNG_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY_BLOB;
        }
        else if (!strcmp(pszObjId, szOID_ECC_PUBLIC_KEY))
        {
            lpszStructType = X509_ECC_PRIVATE_KEY;
        }
        //else if (!strcmp(pszObjId, szOID_X957_DSA) || !strcmp(pszObjId, szOID_OIWSEC_dsa))
        //{
        //  // _PkcsImportPlainTextKeyDsa
        //  // KspImportDsaPrivateKey DSS2 0x32535344
        //  lpszStructType = X509_DSS_PARAMETERS;
        //}
        else
        {
            hr = NTE_BAD_ALGID;
        }

        if (lpszStructType)
        {
            if (HR(hr, CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, lpszStructType,
                PrivateKeyInfo->PrivateKey.pbData, PrivateKeyInfo->PrivateKey.cbData, 
                CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG|CRYPT_DECODE_NOCOPY_FLAG|CRYPT_DECODE_SHARE_OID_STRING_FLAG, 0, &pb, &cb)))
            {
                switch ((ULONG_PTR)lpszStructType)
                {
                case (ULONG_PTR)CNG_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY_BLOB:
                    hr = ImportRsaKey(phKey, BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB, pb, cb);
                    break;

                case (ULONG_PTR)X509_ECC_PRIVATE_KEY:

                    if (!reinterpret_cast<PCRYPT_ECC_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO>(pb)->szCurveOid)
                    {
                        union {
                            PSTR szCurveOid;
                            UCHAR buf[0x20 + sizeof(void*)];
                        };
                        ULONG cbCurveOid = sizeof(buf);

                        if (!HR(hr, CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, X509_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER, 
                            PrivateKeyInfo->Algorithm.Parameters.pbData, 
                            PrivateKeyInfo->Algorithm.Parameters.cbData,
                            CRYPT_DECODE_NOCOPY_FLAG, 0, &szCurveOid, &cbCurveOid)))
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        reinterpret_cast<PCRYPT_ECC_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO>(pb)->szCurveOid = szCurveOid;
                    }

                    hr = ImportEccKey(phKey, 
                        reinterpret_cast<PCRYPT_ECC_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO>(pb), 
                        IsEncryptKey(PrivateKeyInfo->pAttributes));

                    break;
                }

                LocalFree(pb);
            }
        }

        LocalFree(PrivateKeyInfo);
    }

    return hr;
}

struct CryptCNGMap 
{
    struct ENCODE_DECODE_PARA {
        PFN_CRYPT_ALLOC         pfnAlloc;           // OPTIONAL
        PFN_CRYPT_FREE          pfnFree;            // OPTIONAL
    };

    struct SECRET_APPEND
    {
        ULONG IterationCount;
        ULONG cb;
        UCHAR buf[];
    };

    ULONG version;

    NTSTATUS (WINAPI * InitHash)(
        _Out_ BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE* phAlgorithm, 
        _Out_ ULONG* pcbObjectLength,
        _In_ ULONG dwFlags);

    NTSTATUS (WINAPI *InitEncrypt)(
        _Out_ BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE* phAlgorithm, 
        _Out_ ULONG* pcbObjectLength, 
        _In_ BYTE* pbParams, 
        _In_ ULONG cbParams
        );

    NTSTATUS (WINAPI *InitDecrypt)(
        _Out_ BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE* phAlgorithm, 
        _Out_ ULONG* pcbObjectLength, 
        _In_ BYTE* pbParams, 
        _In_ ULONG cbParams
        );

    NTSTATUS (WINAPI *InitEncryptKey)(
        _In_ BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm,
        _Out_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKey,
        _Out_ BYTE* pbKeyObject, 
        _In_ ULONG cbKeyObject,
        _In_ const BYTE* pbSecret,
        _In_ ULONG cbSecret,
        _Out_ BYTE* pbParams,
        _Out_ ULONG cbParams
        );

    NTSTATUS (WINAPI *InitDecryptKey)(
        _In_ BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm,
        _Out_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKey,
        _Out_ BYTE* pbKeyObject, 
        _In_ ULONG cbKeyObject,
        _In_ const BYTE* pbSecret,
        _In_ ULONG cbSecret,
        _Out_ BYTE* pbParams,
        _Out_ ULONG cbParams
        );

    NTSTATUS (WINAPI *PasswordDeriveKey)(
        _In_ CryptCNGMap* map, 
        _In_ UCHAR SECRET_PREPEND,
        _In_ PCWSTR pszPassword,
        _In_ ULONG cbPassword, // wcslen(pszPassword)*sizeof(WCHAR)
        _In_opt_ SECRET_APPEND* p,
        _In_opt_ ULONG cb,
        _Out_ PBYTE pbOutput,
        _Out_ ULONG cbOutput
        );

    NTSTATUS (WINAPI *ParamsEncode)(
        _In_ const BYTE* pb, 
        _In_ ULONG cb, 
        _In_ const ENCODE_DECODE_PARA* pEncodePara,
        _Out_ BYTE** ppbEncoded,
        _Out_ ULONG* pcbEncoded
        );

    NTSTATUS (WINAPI *ParamsDecode)(
        _In_ const BYTE* pbEncoded, 
        _In_ ULONG cbEncoded, 
        _In_ const ENCODE_DECODE_PARA* pDecodePara,
        _Out_ BYTE** ppb,
        _Out_ ULONG* pcb
        );
};

void* WINAPI PkiAlloc(_In_ size_t cbSize)
{
    return LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cbSize);
}

void WINAPI PkiFree(void* pv)
{
    LocalFree(pv);
}

HRESULT GetLastErrorEx(ULONG dwError /*= GetLastError()*/)
{
    NTSTATUS status = RtlGetLastNtStatus();
    return RtlNtStatusToDosErrorNoTeb(status) == dwError ? HRESULT_FROM_NT(status) : HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
}

HRESULT DecryptPrivateKey(_Inout_ PCRYPT_ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO pepki, _In_ PCWSTR pszPassword)
{
    HCRYPTOIDFUNCADDR hFuncAddr;

    if (HCRYPTOIDFUNCSET hFuncSet = CryptInitOIDFunctionSet("CryptCNGPKCS12GetMap", 0))
    {
        union {
            PVOID pvFuncAddr;
            CryptCNGMap* (WINAPI *GetPKCS12Map)();
        };

        if (CryptGetOIDFunctionAddress(hFuncSet, X509_ASN_ENCODING, 
            pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.pszObjId, CRYPT_GET_INSTALLED_OID_FUNC_FLAG, &pvFuncAddr, &hFuncAddr))
        {
            CryptCNGMap* map = GetPKCS12Map();

            static const CryptCNGMap::ENCODE_DECODE_PARA cdp = { PkiAlloc, PkiFree };

            NTSTATUS status;

            if (0 <= (status = map->ParamsDecode(
                pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.pbData,
                pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.cbData, 
                &cdp, 
                &pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.pbData,
                &pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.cbData)))
            {
                ULONG cb;
                BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm;

                if (0 <= (status = map->InitDecrypt(&hAlgorithm, &cb, 
                    pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.pbData,
                    pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.cbData)))
                {
                    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey;

                    PBYTE pbSecret = (PBYTE)pszPassword;
                    ULONG cbSecret = (ULONG)wcslen(pszPassword);

                    struct CRYPT_PKCS12_PBES2_PARAMS
                    {
                        /*00*/BOOL bUTF8;
                        /*04*/CHAR pszObjId[0x20];//szOID_PKCS_5_PBKDF2 "1.2.840.113549.1.5.12"
                        /*24*/ULONG cbSalt;
                        /*28*/UCHAR pbSalt[0x20];
                        /*48*/ULONG cIterations;
                        /*4c*/ULONG pad;
                        /*50*/CHAR pszHMACAlgorithm[0x20];//PKCS12_PBKDF2_ID_HMAC_SHAxxx -> BCRYPT_HMAC_SHAxxx_ALG_HANDLE
                        /*70*/CHAR pszKeyAlgorithm[0x20];//szOID_NIST_AESxxx_CBC
                        /*90*/ULONG cbIV;
                        /*94*/UCHAR pbIV[0x20];
                        /*b4*/
                    };

                    PBYTE pbIV = 0;
                    ULONG cbIV = 0;
                    BOOL bUTF8 = FALSE;

                    CRYPT_PKCS12_PBES2_PARAMS* py = reinterpret_cast<CRYPT_PKCS12_PBES2_PARAMS*>(
                        pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.pbData);

                    if (sizeof(CRYPT_PKCS12_PBES2_PARAMS) == pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.cbData &&
                        !strcmp(szOID_PKCS_5_PBKDF2, py->pszObjId))
                    {
                        pbIV = py->pbIV;
                        cbIV = py->cbIV;
                        if (cbIV > sizeof(py->pbIV))
                        {
                            status = STATUS_BAD_DATA;
                            goto __0;
                        }

                        if (bUTF8 = py->bUTF8)
                        {
                            PSTR psz = 0;
                            ULONG cch = 0;
                            while(cch = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pszPassword, cbSecret, psz, cch, 0, 0))
                            {
                                if (psz)
                                {
                                    pbSecret = (PBYTE)psz;
                                    cbSecret = cch;
                                    break;
                                }

                                psz = (PSTR)alloca(cch);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!bUTF8)
                    {
                        ++cbSecret *= sizeof(WCHAR);
                    }

                    status = map->InitDecryptKey(hAlgorithm, &hKey, 
                        (PBYTE)alloca(cb), cb, pbSecret, cbSecret,
                        pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.pbData,
                        pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.cbData 
                        );

                    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0);

                    if (0 <= status)
                    {
                        status = BCryptDecrypt(hKey, 
                            pepki->EncryptedPrivateKey.pbData,
                            pepki->EncryptedPrivateKey.cbData, 
                            0, pbIV, cbIV, 
                            pepki->EncryptedPrivateKey.pbData,
                            pepki->EncryptedPrivateKey.cbData,
                            &pepki->EncryptedPrivateKey.cbData, 0);

                        BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);
                    }
                }
__0:
                LocalFree(pepki->EncryptionAlgorithm.Parameters.pbData);
            }

            CryptFreeOIDFunctionAddress(hFuncAddr, 0);

            return status ? HRESULT_FROM_NT(status) : STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
    }

    return GetLastErrorEx();
}

HRESULT PkcsImportEncodedKey(_Out_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKey, _In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb, _In_ PCWSTR pszPassword)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    PCRYPT_ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO pepki;
    ULONG s;
    if (HR(hr, CryptDecodeObjectEx(
        X509_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO, 
        pb, cb, CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG|CRYPT_DECODE_SHARE_OID_STRING_FLAG, 0, &pepki, &s)))
    {
        if (S_OK == (hr = DecryptPrivateKey(pepki, pszPassword)))
        {
            hr = PkcsImportPlainTextKey(phKey,
                pepki->EncryptedPrivateKey.pbData,
                pepki->EncryptedPrivateKey.cbData);
        }

        LocalFree(pepki);
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT PkcsImportKey(_Out_ NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKey, _In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb, _In_opt_ PCWSTR pszPassword /*= 0*/)
{
    NCRYPT_PROV_HANDLE hProvider;
    SECURITY_STATUS status = NCryptOpenStorageProvider(&hProvider, MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0);

    if (NOERROR == status)
    {
        NCryptBufferDesc *pParameterList = 0;
        BCryptBuffer buf;
        NCryptBufferDesc ParameterList { NCRYPTBUFFER_VERSION, 1, &buf };

        if (pszPassword)
        {
            buf.BufferType = NCRYPTBUFFER_PKCS_SECRET;
            buf.cbBuffer = (1 + (ULONG)wcslen(pszPassword)) * sizeof(WCHAR);
            buf.pvBuffer = const_cast<PWSTR>(pszPassword);

            pParameterList = &ParameterList;
        }

        NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey;

        status = NCryptImportKey(hProvider, 0, NCRYPT_PKCS8_PRIVATE_KEY_BLOB, 
            pParameterList, &hKey, pb, cb, NCRYPT_DO_NOT_FINALIZE_FLAG);

        NCryptFreeObject(hProvider);

        if (NOERROR == status)
        {
            static const ULONG flags = NCRYPT_ALLOW_EXPORT_FLAG|NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG;

            if (NOERROR == (status = NCryptSetProperty(hKey, NCRYPT_EXPORT_POLICY_PROPERTY, (PBYTE)&flags, sizeof(flags), 0)) &&
                NOERROR == (status = NCryptFinalizeKey(hKey, NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG)))
            {
                *phKey = hKey;

                return NOERROR;
            }

            NCryptFreeObject(hKey);
        }
    }

    return status;
}

HRESULT NKeyToBKey(_Out_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKey, _In_ NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey)
{
    WCHAR szAlgId[0x40];
    ULONG cb = sizeof(szAlgId);

    HRESULT status = NCryptGetProperty(hKey, NCRYPT_ALGORITHM_PROPERTY, (PBYTE)szAlgId, sizeof(szAlgId), &cb, 0);

    if (NOERROR == status)
    {
        cb = 0;
        PBYTE pb = 0;

        while(NOERROR == (status = NCryptExportKey(hKey, 0, BCRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_BLOB, 0, pb, cb, &cb, 0)))
        {
            if (pb)
            {
                BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm;
                if (0 <= (status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlgorithm, szAlgId, 0, 0)))
                {
                    status = BCryptImportKeyPair(hAlgorithm, 0, BCRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_BLOB, phKey, pb, cb, 0);
                    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0);
                }

                break;
            }

            pb = (PBYTE)alloca(cb);
        }
    }

    return status;
}

HRESULT PkcsImportKey(_Out_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKey, _In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb, _In_ PCWSTR pszPassword)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey;
    if (S_OK == (hr = PkcsImportKey(&hKey, pb, cb, pszPassword)))
    {
        hr = NKeyToBKey(phKey, hKey);
        NCryptFreeObject(hKey);
    }

    return hr;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class __declspec(novtable) Pem
{
    virtual HRESULT process(_In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb) = 0;

public:
    virtual ~Pem() = default;

    HRESULT import(_In_reads_(cch) PCSTR psz, _In_ ULONG cch)
    {
        HRESULT hr;

        PBYTE pb = 0;
        ULONG cb = 0;

        while (HR(hr, CryptStringToBinaryA(psz, cch, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, pb, &cb, 0, 0)))
        {
            if (pb)
            {
                hr = process(pb, cb);
                break;
            }

            if (!(pb = new UCHAR[cb]))
            {
                hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (pb) delete [] pb;

        return hr;
    }

    void* operator new(size_t s, void* pv, ULONG cb)
    {
        return cb < s ? 0 : pv;
    }

    void operator delete (void* /*pv*/)
    {
    }
};

class PemCert : public Pem
{
    HCERTSTORE _M_hCertStore;

    virtual HRESULT process(_In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb)
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        HR(hr, CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore(_M_hCertStore, X509_ASN_ENCODING, pb, cb, CERT_STORE_ADD_NEW, 0));
        return hr;
    }

public:

    PemCert(HCERTSTORE hCertStore) : _M_hCertStore(hCertStore)
    {
    }
};

class __declspec(novtable) PemKey : public Pem
{
protected:

    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE _M_hKey = 0;

    virtual ~PemKey()
    {
        if (_M_hKey)
        {
            BCryptDestroyKey(_M_hKey);
        }
    }
public:

    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE get()
    {
        BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = _M_hKey;
        _M_hKey = 0;
        return hKey;
    }
};

struct __declspec(novtable) PemRsaKey : public PemKey
{
    virtual PCSTR GetStructType() = 0;

    virtual PCWSTR GetBlobType() = 0;

    virtual HRESULT process(_In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb)
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        if (HR(hr, CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, GetStructType(), pb, cb, 
            CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG|CRYPT_DECODE_NOCOPY_FLAG|CRYPT_DECODE_SHARE_OID_STRING_FLAG, 0, &pb, &cb)))
        {
            hr = ImportRsaKey(&_M_hKey, GetBlobType(), pb, cb);

            LocalFree(pb);
        }

        return hr;
    }
};

struct PemRsaPublicKey : public PemRsaKey
{
    virtual PCSTR GetStructType() 
    {
        return CNG_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_BLOB;
    }

    virtual PCWSTR GetBlobType()
    {
        return BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB;
    }
};

struct PemRsaPrivateKey : public PemRsaKey
{
    virtual PCSTR GetStructType() 
    {
        return CNG_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY_BLOB;
    }

    virtual PCWSTR GetBlobType()
    {
        return BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB;
    }
};

struct PemPublicKey : public PemKey
{
    virtual HRESULT process(_In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb)
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        PCERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO PublicKeyInfo;

        if (HR(hr, CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, 
            X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, pb, cb, 
            CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG|CRYPT_DECODE_NOCOPY_FLAG|CRYPT_DECODE_SHARE_OID_STRING_FLAG, 
            0, &PublicKeyInfo, &cb)))
        {
            HR(hr, CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx2(X509_ASN_ENCODING, PublicKeyInfo, 0, 0, &_M_hKey));

            LocalFree(PublicKeyInfo);
        }

        return hr;
    }
};

struct PemPrivateKey : public PemKey
{
    virtual HRESULT process(_In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb)
    {
        return PkcsImportPlainTextKey2(&_M_hKey, pb, cb);
    }
};

struct PemEncryptedPrivateKey : public PemPrivateKey
{
    PCWSTR _M_pszPassword;

    PemEncryptedPrivateKey(PCWSTR pszPassword) : _M_pszPassword(pszPassword)
    {
    }

    virtual HRESULT process(_In_reads_(cb) BYTE* pb, _In_ ULONG cb)
    {
        return PkcsImportEncodedKey2(&_M_hKey, pb, cb, _M_pszPassword);
    }
};
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

extern const volatile UCHAR guz = 0;

PSTR __fastcall strnstr(SIZE_T n1, const void* str1, SIZE_T n2, const void* str2);

#define _strnstr(a, b, x) strnstr(RtlPointerToOffset(a, b), a, sizeof(x) - 1, x)

PCSTR IsTag(_In_ PCSTR buf, _In_ PCSTR end, _In_ PCSTR TAG, _In_ ULONG cb)
{
    return end - buf < cb || memcmp(buf, TAG, cb) ? 0 : buf + cb;
}

PCSTR IsBegin(_In_ PCSTR buf, _In_ PCSTR end)
{
    const static char BEGIN[] = "BEGIN";
    return IsTag(buf, end, BEGIN, sizeof(BEGIN) - 1);
}

PCSTR IsEnd(_In_ PCSTR buf, _In_ PCSTR end)
{
    const static char END[] = "END";
    return IsTag(buf, end, END, sizeof(END) - 1);
}

void FreeKeysI(_In_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKeys, _In_ ULONG nKeys)
{
    if (nKeys)
    {
        do 
        {
            BCryptDestroyKey(*phKeys++);
        } while (--nKeys);
    }
}

void FreeKeys(_In_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* phKeys, _In_ ULONG nKeys)
{
    FreeKeysI(phKeys, nKeys);
    LocalFree(phKeys);
}

HRESULT PEMImport(_Out_ HCERTSTORE* phStore,
                  _Out_ BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE** pphKeys,
                  _Out_ ULONG* pnKeys,
                  _In_ PCSTR buf, 
                  _In_ PCSTR end,
                  _In_ PCWSTR pszPassword)
{
    const static char _____[] = "-----";
    const static char ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY[] = "ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY";
    const static char CERTIFICATE[] = "CERTIFICATE";

    enum { fInvalid ,fCert, fEncPrivKey, fPrivKey, fPubKey, fRsaPubKey, fRsaPrivKey } bt;

    *pphKeys = 0;
    *phStore = 0;
    *pnKeys = 0;

    HRESULT hr;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE* keys = (BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE*)stack;
    ULONG nKeys = 0, nCerts = 0;

    if (HCERTSTORE hStore = HR(hr, CertOpenStore(sz_CERT_STORE_PROV_MEMORY, 0, 0, 0, 0)))
    {
        while (buf = _strnstr(buf, end, _____))
        {
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_NT(STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT);

            bt = fInvalid;

            if (!(buf = IsBegin(buf, end - sizeof(_____))) || *buf++ != ' ')
            {
                break;
            }

            PCSTR pcTag = buf;

            if (buf = IsTag(pcTag, end, CERTIFICATE, sizeof(CERTIFICATE) - 1))
            {
                bt = fCert;
            }
            else if (buf = IsTag(pcTag, end, 
                ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY + _countof("ENCRYPTED"), 
                sizeof(ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY) - _countof("ENCRYPTED") - 1))
            {
                bt = fPrivKey;
            }
            else if (buf = IsTag(pcTag, end, ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY, sizeof(ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY) - 1))
            {
                bt = fEncPrivKey;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!(buf = _strnstr(pcTag, end - 2, _____)))
                {
                    break;
                }
                goto __0;
            }

            if (!(buf = IsTag(buf, end - 2, _____, sizeof(_____) - 1)))
            {
                break;
            }

__0:
            ULONG len = RtlPointerToOffset(pcTag, buf);

            PCSTR pc = buf;

            if (!(buf = _strnstr(buf, end, _____)))
            {
                break;
            }

            ULONG cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pc, buf - sizeof(_____));

            if (!(buf = IsEnd(buf, end - sizeof(_____))) || 
                *buf++ != ' ' ||
                !(buf = IsTag(buf, end, pcTag, len)))
            {
                break;
            }

            UCHAR pembuf[sizeof(PemEncryptedPrivateKey)];
            Pem* pem = 0;

            switch (bt)
            {
            case fCert:
                pem = new(pembuf, sizeof(pembuf)) PemCert(hStore);
                break;

            case fPrivKey:
                pem = new(pembuf, sizeof(pembuf)) PemPrivateKey;
                break;

            case fEncPrivKey:
                pem = new(pembuf, sizeof(pembuf)) PemEncryptedPrivateKey(pszPassword);
                break;
            }

            if (pem)
            {
                if (S_OK == (hr = pem->import(pc, cb)))
                {
                    if (fCert == bt)
                    {
                        nCerts++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (--keys < stack)
                        {
                            stack = alloca(sizeof(Pem*));
                        }

                        *keys = static_cast<PemKey*>(pem)->get();
                        
                        if (++nKeys == 128)
                        {
                            hr = STATUS_TOO_MANY_SECRETS;
                        }
                    }
                }

                delete pem;
            }

            if (hr)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (S_OK == hr)
        {
            if (!nKeys && !nCerts)
            {
                hr = STATUS_NOT_FOUND;
            }
            else
            {
                if (nKeys)
                {
                    if (PVOID pv = HR(hr, LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, nKeys * sizeof(BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE))))
                    {
                        *pphKeys = (BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE *)memcpy(pv, keys, nKeys * sizeof(BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE));
                        *pnKeys = nKeys;
                    }
                }

                if (S_OK == hr)
                {
                    *phStore = hStore;
                    return S_OK;
                }
            }
        }

        FreeKeysI(keys, nKeys);
        CertCloseStore(hStore, 0);
    }

    return hr;
}
```